# Got an entropy-ish function for a multinomial distribution? Graph theory and Bayes net related

Tags: entropy, information-theory, graph-theory, bayesian-network, maximum-entropy

I have a discrete variable $X$ that can take on one of three states; $a$, $b$, and $c$. Thus it has two parameters $p_a = P(X = a)$  and $p_b = P(X = b)$, of course $P(X = c) = 1 - p_a - p_b$.

I am looking for an entropy-like function that quantifies uncertainty in this distribution.  So of course the Shannon entropy function looks like

$$
H(p_a, p_b) = - p_a \log_2(p_a) + - p_b \log_2(p_b) + - (1 - p_a - p_b) \log_2(1 - p_a - p_b) .
$$

The maximum of this function is $p_a = p_b = 1/3$.

My problem is that I need a function that behaves like entropy, but the maximum is at $p_a = 1/2, p_b = 1/4$.

The reason I need this is because $X$ is only one of several random variables with a covariance structure between them.  In other words, I have a *multivariate trinomial distribution*.  Further, analysis of the covariance matrix reveals a key property, that entropy for the joint distribution is achieved the closer each marginal distribution is to $p_a = 1/2, p_b = 1/4$, and maximal entropy is achieved when each marginal distribution is at $p_a = 1/2, p_b = 1/4$. So how can I adjust the marginal entropy function to represent this?  I want that same nice inverse u-curve I'd get in the independent variable case, and ideally a similar interpretation to the original entropy function.

**PS**

This is actually a graph theory problem, but I thought it would be better to write it in general terms.  I am trying to evaluate edge-wise entropy in a directed acyclic graph (DAG), where $p_a$ is the probability of no edge, $p_b$ the edge exists in one direction, and $1 - p_a - p_c$ is the probability it exists in the other.  I found a paper that shows that for a directed network with the acyclicity constraint, as the number of nodes goes to infinity, the maximal entropy distribution for the overall network is achieved when each directed edge is $p_a = 1/2, p_b = 1/4$.  So I want an entropy function for each directed edge that skews the general Shannon entropy function to this point as a mode, but, you know, is still an entropy function.

Comment: How particular are you about it's derivation?  Could I do a spline fit of the results of a stochastic simulation?